# Java wildcard difference in 7 and 8

Tags: java, generics

I have the following code, which works fine on Java 8:

```
List<Class<?>> KEY_NAME_CLASSES = Collections.singletonList(String.class);
```

But when I try to use the Java 7 compiler, I get an error:

```
incompatible types: java.util.List<java.lang.Class<java.lang.String>> cannot be converted to java.util.List<java.lang.Class<?>>
```

Why? Is there some way to use such wildcards in Java 7?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Type inference differs significantly in Java-7 and Java-8. In short, to determine the expression type Java-7 uses only the expression itself while Java-8 can use the surrounding context. So the type of the expression `Collections.singletonList(String.class)` in Java-7 is the most precise type which could be determined from this expression, namely `List<Class<String>>`. Java-8 is smarter: it also looks that this expression is assigned to another yet compatible type `List<Class<?>>`, so it sets the type of `Collections.singletonList(String.class)` to `List<Class<?>>` as well.

To make this code working in Java-7 you should specify the generic type explicitly:

```
List<Class<?>> KEY_NAME_CLASSES = Collections.<Class<?>>singletonList(String.class);
```